# tabBarOptions not applied to project (React Native)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a small app that has a to-do list and a calendar. At the bottom is a bottom tab navigator. Everything works and is functional, however, when I try to add `style: {}` inside `tabBarOptions` it isn't being applied. Changing `activeTintColor`, `inactiveTintColor` and `labelStyle` works just fine.

I tried to create a stylesheet and replace everything inside tabBarOptions, but that didn't work. My main goal is to simply create a slightly larger bar along the bottom of the screen. I don't even want a crazy custom navigation bar, just slightly larger so I can make the items inside a little bigger.

MainContainer Class:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

//screens 
import Calendar from './screens/Calendar';
import ToDoList from './screens/ToDoList';

// Screen names
const calendarName = 'Calendar';
const ToDoListName = 'To Do List';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function MainContainer() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator
                tabBarOptions={{
                    activeTintColor: 'tomato',
                    inactiveTintColor: 'black',
                    labelStyle: {paddingBottom: 10, fontSize: 10},
                    style: {padding: 10, height: 70},
                }}
                initialRouteName={ToDoListName}
                           screenOptions={({route}) => ({
                               tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
                                   let iconName;
                                   let rn = route.name;

                                   if (rn === ToDoListName) {
                                       iconName = focused ? 'list' : 'list-outline'; //icons in package. Change later.
                                   } else if (rn === calendarName) {
                                       iconName = focused ? 'calendar' : 'calendar-outline'
                                   }
                                   return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color}/>
                               },
                           })}>

                <Tab.Screen name={ToDoListName} component={ToDoList}/>
                <Tab.Screen name={calendarName} component={Calendar}/>

            </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

For reference here is my ToDoList class

```
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Platform, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import Task from '../../components/Task';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-web';


export default function ToDoList() {
    const [task, setTask] = useState();
    const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState([]);

    const handleAddTask = () => {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
        setTaskItems([...taskItems, task])
        setTask(null);
    }


    const completeTask = (index) => {
        let itemsCopy = [...taskItems];
        itemsCopy.splice(index, 1);
        setTaskItems(itemsCopy)
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {/* Scroll View when list gets longer than page */}
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{
                flexGrow: 1
            }} keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>

                {/*Today's Tasks */}
                <View style={styles.tasksWrapper}>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Today's Tasks</Text>
                    <View style={styles.items}>
                        {/* This is where the tasks will go*/}
                        {
                            taskItems.map((item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => completeTask(index)}>
                                        <Task text={item} />
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </View>
                </View>

            </ScrollView>

            {/* Write a task section */}
            {/* Uses a keyboard avoiding view which ensures the keyboard does not cover the items on screen */}
            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
                style={styles.writeTaskWrapper}>
                <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={'Write a task'} value={task} onChangeText={text => setTask(text)} />
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAddTask()}>
                    <View style={styles.addWrapper}>
                        <Text style={styles.addText}>+</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#E8EAED',
    },
    tasksWrapper: {
        paddingTop: 20,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
    },
    sectionTitle: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    items: {
        marginTop: 30,
    },
    writeTaskWrapper: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 20,
        paddingLeft: 10,
        paddingRight: 10,
        width: '100%',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    input: {
        paddingVertical: 15,
        width: 250,
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        borderRadius: 60,
        borderColor: '#C0C0C0',
        borderWidth: 1,
    },
    addWrapper: {
        width: 60,
        height: 60,
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        borderRadius: 60,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderColor: '#C0C0C0',
        borderWidth: 1,
    },
    addText: {

    },

});
```

And my Calendar class

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
export default function Calendar(){

    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Calendar Will go here</Text>
        </View>
    )

}
```

I made a Task component for the ToDoList. Not sure if you need it to solve this but I'll paste it here anyway.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-web';

const Task = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.item}>
            <View style={styles.itemLeft}>
                <View style={styles.square}></View>
                <Text style={styles.itemText}>{props.text}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.circular}></View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    item: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        padding: 15,
        borderRadius: 10,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        marginBottom: 20,

    },
    itemLeft: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
    },
    square: {
        width: 24,
        height: 24,
        backgroundColor: '#55BCF6',
        opacity: .4,
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginRight: 15,
    },
    itemText: {
        maxWidth: '80%',

    },
    circular: {
        width: 12,
        height: 12,
        borderColor: '#55BCF6',
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderRadius: 5
    },
});

export default Task;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing to solve this was to put the styling inside the `screenOptions`. I didn't want to do this because I wanted to separate the styling from the logic, but it solved the problem for me. See code below:

```
export default function MainContainer() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator

                initialRouteName={ToDoListName}
                           screenOptions={({route}) => ({
                               tabBarIcon: ({focused, color, size}) => {
                                   let iconName;
                                   let rn = route.name;

                                   if (rn === ToDoListName) {
                                       iconName = focused ? 'list' : 'list-outline'; //icons in package. Change later.
                                   } else if (rn === calendarName) {
                                       iconName = focused ? 'calendar' : 'calendar-outline'
                                   }
                                   return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color}/>
                               },
                               activeTintColor: 'tomato',
                               inactiveTintColor: 'black',
                               tabBarShowLabel: false,
                               tabBarStyle: {padding: 10, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'black'},
                           })}>

                <Tab.Screen name={ToDoListName} component={ToDoList}/>
                <Tab.Screen name={calendarName} component={Calendar}/>

            </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the `tabBarStyle` property. You should be able to rename `style` (which is not a supported prop of the tab navigator) to `tabBarStyle`.

Here's the spot in the docs that mentions this. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#tabbarstyle

Answer (score 0):

should incase the 'activeTintColor' and 'inactiveTintColor' don't work, make use of 'tabBarActiveTintColor' and 'tabBarInactiveTintColor'.[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfcLf.png)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35661429)